# Drupal 7 - How add posfix '.html' to all paths?

Tags: uri

is it possible to add to all path system or node path postfix '.html'
for example

```
site.com/index -> site.com/index.html
site.com/user/login -> site.com/user/login.html
site.com/node/add/page -> site.com/node/add/page.html
```

pathauto

```
site.com/term-alias/hello-world -> site.com/term-alias/hello-world.html
```

and so on

Is it?

Comment: From what I know Drupal depends too on apache mod_rewrite to "beautify" its urls and hide the "?q=". Take a look on mod_rewrite doc too.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? See http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI under "What to leave out"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to simply configure Drupal for that. If you serve your Drupal site with Apache, you can configure [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to remove the `.html` suffix. But you will not be able to configure Drupal to add it to the links it produce.

In [a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112), you could [implement](http://drupal.org/node/292) [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) and [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) to remove/add to `.html` suffix to all paths.